# ¿Cómo ir de una página javascript a un servlet sin perder los datos?

Tags: javascript, servlets

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

Hola buenas tardes, mi duda es la siguiente. En este formulario, una vez rellenado, me tengo que redirigir a un servlet para hacer una gestión con ficheros y luego volver a este mismo formulario pero manteniendo los datos en el mismo, o sea, sin perder los datos que ya había escrito en el mismo una vez vuelto del servlet ¿Cómo podría ir desde este formulario al servlet, y luego volver al formulario sin perder los datos que están en las cajas de texto que previamente había rellenado?

Gracias y un saludo.

P.D--> Accedo de la siguiente manera:

function aceptar_Documento(){

```
if (!$('txtNumeroInscripcion').value) throw new Error('Falta el número de inscripción.');

var numIns = document.getElementById('txtNumeroInscripcion').value;

document.getElementById('<%=Constantes.PANT_NUMERO_REGISTRO%>').value = numIns;

document.frm_insertar.<%=Constantes.PANT_SERVLET_ACCION%>.value='<%=Constantes.SERVLET_ACCION_INSERTAR%>';
document.getElementById('frm_insertar').action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/**DocumentosServlet.do**";
document.getElementById('frm_insertar').submit();
```

}

" id="" value=""/>
        " name="" />
        " name="" value="inscripcion"/>

```
        <div class="contenedor_simple">
            <div class="form_contenedor" style="width:94%;left:2.5%;">
                <div class="form_superior">
                    <label>Seleccionar documento :</label>
                </div>
                <table width="100%">
                    <tr style="height: 20px;">
                        <td style="width: 20px;text-align: left;height: 20px;padding-left: 15px; font-weight: bold">
                            <span>Documento</span>
                        </td>
                        <td width="50px"></td>
                        <td style="width: 60px;padding-right: 5px;">
                            <input type="file" id="documento" name="documento" size="49" title="Examinar sistema de archivos"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="contenedor_simple">
            <div style="text-align:center;padding-top:30px;width:99%">
                 <div id="aceptar" onmouseover="enfocar(this)" onmouseout="abandonar(this)" onmousedown="pulsar(this)" onmouseup="soltar(this)" style="width:1%;display:inline;cursor:pointer;">
                    <img id="img_aceptar" onclick="aceptar_Documento()" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/img/Botones/aceptar.gif" alt="Aceptar"/>
                 </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Y regreso del servlet de la siguiente manera:
**Servlet**
private void insertar(final HttpServletRequest request,final HttpServletResponse response) throws MinisterioException, IOException{
// Para peticiones que son Multipart
// Comprobamos que la petición es multipart/form-data
//multipart/form-data: Se usa solo con formularios que contienen un campo de selección de ficheros.
final boolean isMultipart = isMultipartContent(request);
if (!isMultipart) throw new MinisterioException("La petición no es multipart");

```
    if (multi==null){
        // Tratamiento del fichero ( libreria cos.jar - O'Reilly )
        final String dirName = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
        multi = new MultipartRequest(request, dirName,FILE_BYTES_MAX, "ISO-8859-1", new DefaultFileRenamePolicy());
    }
    final String sNumeroRegistro = multi.getParameter(Constantes.PANT_NUMERO_REGISTRO);
    final String sProcedencia = multi.getParameter(Constantes.PANT_PROCEDENCIA);
    final String sProvinciaIns = multi.getParameter(Constantes.PROVINCIA_INSCRIPCION);
    final String sAnioAdquisicion = multi.getParameter(Constantes.ANIO_INSCRIPCION);
    final String sIdDocumento = multi.getParameter(Constantes.ID_DOCUMENTO);
    final String guardado = "SI";

    // Convertimos el archivo en tipo File
    final File archivo = multi.getFile("documento");

    final Validacion v = new Validacion();
    // Comprobamos que se haya seleccionado un archivo
    v.validaDocumento(archivo);

    try(final FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(archivo)){
        final byte[] bDoc = new byte[fis.available()];
        fis.read(bDoc);
        
        final Documentos oDocumento = new Documentos();
        // Recogemos el nombre del fichero
        oDocumento.setNombre(archivo.getName());
        oDocumento.setVisibleCiudadano("N");
        oDocumento.setIdTipoDocumento("9");
        oDocumento.setFecha(new Date());

        // Objeto para insertar los documentos en GD y SCE
        final DaoWS daoW = new DaoWS();
        
        // 14/02/2020 - SÓLO LOS FUNCIONARIOS USAN LA APLICACIÓN, POR TANTO EL ORIGEN DE TODOS LOS DOCUMENTOS 
        //            - ADJUNTADOS POR ESTA VÍA SE MARCAN  COMO FUNCIONARIO.
        //            - EL TIPO DE SOLICITANTE DEBERÍA PERTENECER A LA SOLICITUD, NO AL ORIGEN DEL DOCUMENTO.    
      oDocumento.setUsuario(ISedeBackOffice.TIPO_SOLICITANTE_FUNCIONARIO);
        
      oDocumento.setIdRepositorio(Util.getPropiedad(Constantes.REPOSITORIO));
    
      // Se inserta en el gestor documental propio de la aplicación
      oDocumento.setIdDocumento(daoW.insertarDocumentoGD(bDoc, oDocumento.getNombre()));
    
      // 14/02/2020 - USUARIO SOLICITA QUE TODOS LOS DOCUMENTOS ADJUNTADOS POR FUNCIONARIO PUEDAN SER BORRADOS -
      //              - POR LO TANTO, INDEPENDIENTEMENTE DE SU VISIBILIDAD, SON BORRABLES.                       -          
      // oDocumento.setUsuario(ISedeBackOffice.TIPO_SOLICITANTE_FUNCIONARIO);
        // Objeto para insertar en BBDD
      dao.grabarDocumento(sNumeroRegistro, oDocumento);
    
      dao.commit();

      // Redirige al listado de documentos del registro actual
      if(sProcedencia.equalsIgnoreCase("inscripcionDetalle")) {
          response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/inscripcionDetalle.jsp?NUMINSCRIPCION="+sNumeroRegistro+"&PROVINSCRIPCION="+sProvinciaIns+
                  "&ANIOADQUISICION="+sAnioAdquisicion+"&IDDOCUMENTO="+sIdDocumento+"&SUBIDO"+guardado);
      } else {
          if (sProcedencia.equalsIgnoreCase("inscripcion")) {
              response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/inscripcion.jsp?NUMINSCRIPCION="+sNumeroRegistro+"&PROVINSCRIPCION="+sProvinciaIns+
                      "&ANIOADQUISICION="+sAnioAdquisicion+"&IDDOCUMENTO="+sIdDocumento+"&SUBIDO"+guardado);
          }
      }
      
    } catch (final DBException e) {
        log.fatal("ERROR",e);
        if (dao!=null) dao.rollback();
        throw new MinisterioException("No se ha podido conectar a la BD");
    } catch (final MinisterioException me) {
        if (dao!=null) dao.rollback();
        throw me;
    }finally{
        if (dao!= null) dao.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage y https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Esa pregunta tiene múltiples respuestas, así que es muy probable que recibas ayuda más útil si compartes el código relevante. Cómo estás haciendo la redirección al servlet? Cómo estás volviendo al formulario? Usas algún framework en el formulario? Mostrar una imagen del formulario no nos dice mayor cosa... revisa localStorage para mantener cosas del lado del cliente, o revisa cómo podrías enviar los datos al servidor y mantener una sesión de usuario en el backend. De nuevo, depende de los requerimientos de tu solución

Comment: Accedo de la siguiente manera: